# Block with jQuery autocomplete in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, jquery, autocomplete

How can I add jQuery autocomplete to checkout custom block?

Part of my js file code:

```
 if (...) {
   $(".hello").not(".red").hide();
   $(".red").show();
   var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp"];
   $(".hello").click(function () {
      $(".hello").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
   });
...
```

"*I have removed the error message, because the answers I accepted is not solution to it.*"

Comment: share your code in layout file, where you can add this to checkout.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checkout one page application use knockout for rendering and binding. If you need to work with DOM elements (like via jquery ui library) you should use [afterRender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove) knockout binding.

*Example:*

**my-template.html:**

`<input data-bind="afterRender: setSearchElement" />`

**my-component.js:**

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        setSearchElement: function (element) {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp"
            ];
            $(element).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="my-component" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">path-to-js/my-component</item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">path-to-template/my-template</item>
</item>
```

*Result:*

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $ with jQuery in your added script and try again

```
if (...) {
   jQuery(".hello").not(".red").hide();
   jQuery(".red").show();
   var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp"];
   jQuery(".hello").click(function () {
      jQuery(".hello").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
   });
...
```

Comment: It does not make any difference if I use $ or jQuery. I have checked with Chrome console the js file content (if changes has taken place in it).