# Magento 2 & JQuery.UI.Autocomplete

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs, autocomplete

I would like to use `JQuery.UI.Autocomplete` component in my module for `Magento 2`. 
Also, I am using KO.js for the user interface of my application. 
So, I have added a custom binding for KO:

```
define([
'ko',
'jquery',
'jquery/ui'
], function (ko, $) {
'use strict';

ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var settings = valueAccessor();
        var selectedOption = settings.selected;
        var options = settings.options();
        var updateElementValueWithLabel = function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(element).val(ui.item.label);
            if(typeof ui.item !== "undefined") {
                selectedOption(ui.item);
            }
        };

        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: options,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

I've added the following code in my html template:

```
<div class="suggestions">
<input id="suggestion_box" type="text" data-bind="autoComplete: { selected: $data.productSuggestions.selectedSuggestion, options: $data.productSuggestions.suggestions }" />
</div>
```

It looks good, but it doesn't work. I've got a error message in the browser console. I debugged it and as it turned out, the reason of the issue is in the following lines(they start from the `6819` line) of `jquery-ui.js` library:

```
this.menu = $( "<ul>" )
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete ui-front" )
            .appendTo( this._appendTo() )
            .menu({
                // disable ARIA support, the live region takes care of that
                role: null
            })
            .hide()
            .data( "ui-menu" );
```

The `this.menu` field is undefined, because of invoking `data( "ui-menu" )` method. Methods that invoke before `data()` one are returns their results.

It seems like I've inited `JQuery.UI.Autocomplete` in a wrong way, but all examples of configuring are quite simple and I'm not sure what have I done wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery ui menu extended in magento core library `lib/web/mage/menu.js` as `mage.menu`.
jQuery generate widgetName for any component

```
name = name.split( "." )[ 1 ];
fullName = namespace + "-" + name;
```

Widget name used as attribute name for storage widget instance in widget DOM elements.

```
$.data( element, this.widgetName, this );
```

After extending by magento core widget name changed from `ui-menu` to `mage-menu` and `element.data("ui-menu")` become `undefined`.

Keep in mind that magento use different jquery-ui versions for frontend and backend and in one from this versions this issue reproduced (in frontend if I remember correctly)

---

**You can use mixin as workaround for this issue**

*require-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/menu': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/lib/mage/menu-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/lib/mage/menu-mixin.js*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {

        $.widget('mage.menu', data.menu, {
            _create: function () {
                $(this.element).data('ui-menu', this);
                this._super();
            }
        });

        data.menu = $.mage.menu;

        return data;
    };
});
```

Comment: I have tried it. but still not working. Any idea?

Comment: its not working

Comment: 2 things need to be change for it to work from the above answer (_At least for Magento 2.3.1_). **1.** File name **require-config.js** must be **requirejs-config.js.** **2.**  `$.widget('mage.menu', data.menu,` must be `$.widget('mage.menu', $.ui.menu, { `

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The small issue needs to be corrected in the above accepted answer

Please change

```
require-config.js to requirejs-config.js
```

Comment: @max You answer worked for me but you need to change require-config.js to requirejs-config.js